# What is wrong with this Json array syntax?

Tags: json, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a web request to Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a message. The raw data as sent with `Content-Type:application/json"` is:

> { "to":"ecO8y..._D", "data": [ {"msisdn":"+1111111" }, {"b":"c"} ] }

Firebase responds with this error message:

> Field "data" must be a JSON array: [{"msisdn":"+1111111"},{"b":"c"}]

Is there something wrong with the text that I have entered for the `data` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "JSON array" wording is confusing here. The `data` needs to be a JSON object with a single level of properties, so:

```
{
  "to":"ecO8y..._D", 
  "data": {
    "msisdn":"+1111111", 
    "b":"c"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, data can't have hierarchical data or array of elements. It can contain only one level child elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to send data from your application server to FCM, you will get 400 error, if data element contains hierarchical data or array of elements.

Data with one level of child element works.

```
{"message":{"topic":"users","data":{"name":"srao","pho":"38743"}}}
```

Data with array of element doesn't work.

```
{"message":{"topic":"users","data":[{"name":"grag","pho":"38743"},{"name":"boney","pho":"3899943"}]}}
```

Data with multiple levels or hierarchy doesn't work.

```
 {"message":{"topic":"users","data": {"person" : {"name":"srao","pho":"38743"}}}}
```